# android studio read dart from wrong path in linux zorin

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-studio

i use from flutter in android studio flamingo in zorin linux(based on ubuntu)

i installed flutter from snap and later download other versions of flutter and extract them to snap path
[image]

i have a flutter project that used flutter sdk 3.13.5 and dart 3.1.2
i set these setting in android studio like image:
flutter sdk path:
[image]

and dart sdk path:
[image]

When I run the command "which flutter dart" it gives me the following output

/snap/bin/flutter
/snap/bin/dart

my flutter setting in pubspec is like:

environment:
sdk: '>=3.1.0 <4.0.0'

and when i run the command "flutter run", it say to me "Because ecommerce_flutter requires SDK version >=3.1.0 <4.0.0, version solving failed."

What is wrong with my work?
How do I solve this problem?